# Composition of typescript generics

Tags: typescript, generics, domain-driven-design, composition

I am trying to create a system for domain modelling in typescript, influenced strongly by Scott Wlaschin's *Domain Modelling Made Functional* which is based on F#.

I am having trouble finding the correct way to handle the passing around of generic properties, so that a generic object type can specify a property as being of some form of another generic type with out forcing resolution immediately. Very hard to explain in text so here is a code example of roughly the kind of thing I am trying to achieve:

```
// We create a Simple generic so that we can
// prevent the direct use of primitives
// giving us an oppotunity to validate input (see make* fns below)
type Simple<
    Input extends
        | string
        | number
        | boolean,
    Tag extends string
> = Input & Record<Tag, never>

// We create an Id type which is a Simple string
type Id<Tag extends string> = Simple<string, Tag>

// We create an Entity type which accepts a
// string indexed interface with any Simple type as it's properties
// and a Tag which is passed down to lock the Id type
type Entity<
    Input extends {[index: string]: Simple},
    Tag extends string
> = Input & { id: Id<Tag> }

// We create a Deal type
// which is an Entity with an Id tagged with 'deal'
type Deal = Entity<{
    name: DealName
}, 'deal'>

// We define our Deal property types
type DealId = Id<'deal'>
type DealName = Simple<string, 'dealName'>

// we define Factories for creating
// our Deal properties and our Deals
// as the types are locked by the tags,
// this is now the only way to create them.
// This means once we have a Deal instance at run time,
// we know it has been validated
const makeDealId = (input: string) => {
    // validate deal id here
    return input as DealId
} 

const makeDealName = (input: string): DealName => {
    // validate deal name here
    return input as DealName
}

const makeDeal = (input: {
    id: DealId
    name: DealName
}): Deal => {
    // validate deal here
    return input as Deal
}

// Fails
const dealIdA: DealId = 'qwerty' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'DealId'
const dealNameA: DealName = 'Deal A' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'DealName'
const dealA: Deal = {
    id: dealIdA,
    name: dealNameA,
}

// Succeed
const dealIdB =  makeDealId('qwerty')
const dealNameB = makeDealName('Deal B')
const dealB: Deal = makeDeal({
    id: dealIdB,
    name: dealNameB,
})

// dealB is a valid Deal
```

**This a very stripped down version that is hopefully just enough to be illustrative, but doesn't include nested Entities and ValueObjects and applying constraints etc.*

The problem is that the Entity definition is invalid as Simple is a generic and we are not providing it's arguments, se we get this error:

```
Generic type 'Simple' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

However at this point we don't care what form of Simple we take, only that the property must be some kind of Simple thing, and not a string | number | boolean, or anything else...

I have tried things like:

```
type Entity<
    Input extends {[index: string]: Simple<unknown>},
    Tag extends string
> = Input & { id: Id<Tag> }
```

and even (as dirty as it is):

```
type Entity<
    Input extends {[index: string]: Simple<any>},
    Tag extends string
> = Input & { id: Id<Tag> }
```

I am obviously missing something here conceptually. If anybody fancies trying to get their head around it and pointing me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

** one thing to note, for better or worse I am trying to make this as functional as possible (because my brain likes it and because it helps keep it inline with Scott's F# ideas), hense all types are declared 'types' with no interfaces or classes*

Comment: It sounds like you want higher-kinded types (being generic in how you're being generic).  https://github.com/pelotom/hkts presents an encoding of HKTs in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks @LeviRamsey! That does look helpful. On first read approximately 99.99% of it went over my head but I will have another look tomorrow after a good nights sleep :) Seems like I am going to need to get more fluency with functional terminology, which is no bad thing.

Comment: Could you explain what you think the type `Input & Record<Tag, never>` does? Are you wishing to validate `Tag` here, or do you actually mean that you want an intersection of `string` and `Record` (a mapped object)?

Comment: @evelynhathaway The idea with this is to secure a primitive type at compile time so that multiple strings can be discriminated against. In the following example we could pass either deal name or account name to the function as all it specifies here is a string.

`const accountName = 'Account A'`
`const dealName = 'Deal A'`
`type UseDealName = (name: string) => void`

Comment: This means it will be possible to accidentally pass the wrong thing. By "tagging" the `string` type with a `{[index: string]: never}` we are essentially adding an invisible annotation to the string type as a way of distinguishing strings. As we use never for the value type, the compiler never expects to see it and the variable is still just treated as a string at run time, but we can lock down functions so they only accept the right 'kind of string' at compile time.

Comment: Also as the only way to get a value of one of these type is to cast it, if you stick to a convention to only cast in factory functions then you can ensure and value of one of these types has been created by the factory function, which can enforce validation. This allows us to use our factories to process and validate data at the boundary of our code and avoid defensive programming in our business logic.

I would really like to constrain the behaviour to not rely on conventions because this is all redundant if you just cast a string to your tagged string type, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generic type 'Simple' requires 2 type argument(s).

You always must supply generic parameters to a generic type. The only exception to that is when those generic parameters have defaults, but that's not the case here.

What you can do is pass in the original constraints of those generic parameters as a way to say "I do not want to further constrain the generic parameter here"

```
type Entity<
    Input extends Record<string, Simple<string | number | boolean, string>>,
    Tag extends string
> = Input & { id: Id<Tag> }
```

`string | number | boolean` comes from the constraint for `Simple`'s `Input`, and `string` comes from the constraint for `Simple`'s `Tag`.

Now `Entity` can receive a more specific type which will get passed through.

---

The downside is that you have the same constraint in two places, which may be difficult to maintain. But that's easily fixed with an additional type alias:

```
type SimpleInputConstraint = string | number | boolean

type Simple<
  Input extends SimpleInputConstraint,
  Tag extends string
> = //...

type Entity<
    Input extends Record<string, Simple<SimpleInputConstraint, string>>,
    Tag extends string
> = //...
```

---

However, now theres a new problem:

```
type Deal = Entity<{
    name: Simple<string, 'dealName'>
}, 'deal'>
// Index signature is missing in type 'String & Record<"dealName", never>'.(2344)
```

*Disclaimer: The following explanation may not be correct, but it's as best as I understand it. Sometimes doing work with advanced typescript types is just trying different arrangements of things until typescript likes it, and doing your best to understand why that actually worked.*

The problem is that a `Record<K, V>` is shorthand for `{ [key in K]: V }`, which is the syntax for defining an index signature. Yet `string` (or the other primitive types) cannot be indexed as such.  So I don't believe your method of branding here will work.

Instead if you brand `Simple` with a known key, then no index signature is required, and everything should work.

```
type Simple<
    Input extends SimpleInputConstraint,
    Tag extends string
> = Input & { _tag: Tag }
```

This should be just as safe, since you can't really make a `string & { tag: 'foo' }` at runtime.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=19&pln=7&pc=40&strict=true#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-sDBJRUrioFNNnFVKs1yMaPsZqg9t86-tqYma4qb33xWmv3O8wwFAQEDB1aco8zI8re64AHK-hA9r8tIkKgXeFQwQKQpwne4TUGE2CCM+G7OpAZCHhSHoUlAuGngwk5gUhsGkbhkF-m8gGVjeiHIAx0GwVufgQBhJhQAAYsa0bMO6PRlouiJkkKBDYWR65RGQLqEXAYnetkcm4R6Qohgm0DEZkGhQLGHRorwJQ+GeLDEJ2Qo2EGQYYEMenZBgyAlPYFAWZYCJij4CAAHRJBc2LbH+EjbEQJqOFAtieJk8kvtQpASCadhkIUViIBAtmKDFbROfYeK0LY2z8MYUDlJU1TaL4MilocUCtB05FogwDR1LgYJcsM9CvJ+XbzEKVVVGKbFjrFAgQF+UAaAUZAop1tC6a1MiQlAAoNaQTXtBA9FQW8HUfMA3XASwwxgvtjF0P1M3DRUo1IuNP6MYmGgzXN2GLcdmTbFd01wZtja0M1e0Ke1S1ggNOZVJd65UjNL3-ol7FQWtF0o31fx3YoI01TxL5vQDOafQtWrLCt65rShihCXAyAelttBsVSACCcMVBRN4AI6OIRID2lAQoXGmjpnYLjn5L9xBwCwP68Na0Y2jerUPtITNQGxHHsyjHFvPauFQKzgvC6LXIS9sTnLaGsvy4rlikQbEFQWrGtsTrhsMNDCyw5r8O+KznY5kjYJa1BgfU3OQowNgSoQLq9XA37nO+AAQm8O0tf7DT2rzroC6M6tJ2Hf7pwwoP-Tnhup-ahdu+uqccxu5e7bhDTe-Mvss2nQcLCHyeo6XnaQoXSRsenQa6HjKNAA)

Comment: I am 99% sure you are absolutely right, and thank you! Absolute hero. I wanted to use the 'never' in the tag to make it explicit that this was an artificial construction as it is a bit of a hack, but if it doesn't work then it doesn't work. I am just trying to reconstruct my solution according to your suggestion and should it work out I will mark yours as the solution, and if you don't mind add an edit with a bit of detail of what I end up with.